# File privileges mySql in Cpanel

Tags: mysql, cpanel

How do I set file privilege for user of MySQL database in cpanel. I have tried

```
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET File_priv = 'Y' WHERE User = 'db_user';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

With no success
I have tried the code inside the database

Comment: Possible duplicate? These are two different questions !

Comment: If you tried, put your error message. Error messages are the best way to find the root of the problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Cpanel put on my.cnf local-infile=0

You must put on /etc/my.cnf

```
local-infile=1
```

After restart mysql